# Simple nginx/Angular project force HTTPS

Tags: angular, nginx

I have a really simple Docker container running an Angular app in nginx v1.13 that I want to enforce HTTPS on.

I've tried setting rewrite rules but I either only get it working on the root domain (ie: http://myapp.com -> https://myapp.com), but not on pages (ie: http://myapp.com/login stays http)

I've tried different combos of $localhost, $host, $server_name, and $request_uri but I usually end up with a 'too many redirects' error.

My domain has an SSL certificate that is working with other apps hosted in IIS, so I'm pretty sure it's just my nginx config.

Here is the config file (unchanged from the image):

```

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

```
#charset koi8-r;
#access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

location /(assets)/  {
    gzip_static on;
    gzip_types text/plain text/xml text/css
    text/comma-separated-values
    text/javascript application/x-javascript
    application/atom+xml;

    expires off;
}
#error_page  404              /404.html;

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

# proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
#}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#    root           html;
#    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
#    fastcgi_index  index.php;
#    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
#    include        fastcgi_params;
#}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
#location ~ /\.ht {
#    deny  all;
#}
```

}

```

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for the help, but it turned out to be an Azure configuration problem. I had to set the Custom Domains options to allow SSL Redirect.

When running the container locally, the suggestion from @MatTheWhale seemed to have an impact on my service, although I can't 100% confirm it since `localhost` is never a true replica of a domain

Comment: [Read the SSL termination documentation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/nginx-ssl-termination/) for Nginx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For HTTPS forcing, I usually add something like this in my conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myapp.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Then make another server block for where the HTTP requests will get redirected to, and move all the actual configurations there:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name myapp.com;

    # Move all your location blocks here
}
```